# python/pandas - Вхождение во временной интервал

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Имеется заведение, которое работает круглосуточно.
В датафрейме имеется информация о том, во сколько клиент посещал заведение (например, с 07:30 до 09:05) (два столбца, когда пришел и когда ушел). Таких строк более 10тыс.

При этом, руководство хочет знать, сколько % от общего количества людей приходится на самое загруженное время заведения? (с 9:00 до 11:00).

Хочу получить количество минут для каждой строки, которая входит в этот указанный интервал, но не понимаю, как это можно реализовать. Например, в примере выше, это были бы только 5 минут (4,16% входит в целевой интервал времени).

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd - почитайте, если вам действительно нужен ответ.

Comment: Приведите воспроизводимый пример данных. Хотя бы - в каком формате приведены данные о начале и конце посещения. От формата данных полностью зависит то, как вы будете данные обрабатывать.

Answer (score 3):

1. Просматриваем все строки и удаляем те, в которых ни начало ни конец не попадают в интервал 9:00 - 11:00
2. Просматриваем все оставшиеся строки и анализируем начало и конец:
3. Если начало раньше 9:00 -> сдвигаем до девяти
4. Если конец позже 11:00 -> сдвигаем на 11
5. В каждой строке вычисляем разность - получаем время пребывания.

Но зачем Вам это нужно?! На вопрос начальства это ответить не поможет. Ответ на этот вопрос даёт просто количество строк, оставшихся в датафрейме после 1. И всё...